# Mistake in this fold implementation

Tags: haskell, recursion, pattern-matching

In [this lecture](http://www.seas.upenn.edu/~cis194/lectures/02-lists.html) about Haskell programming, there is a fold implementation, defined like so :

```
fold :: (a -> b -> b) -> b  -> [a] -> b
fold f z []     = z
fold f z (x:xs) = f x (fold z f xs)
```

The idea is to use it to define sum, product, etc...

```
sum''     = fold (+) 0
product'' = fold (*) 1
length''  = fold addOne 0
 where addOne _ s = 1 + s
```

There seems to be an inversion between `z` and `f` inside the recursion pattern: otherwise, how could `z f xs` match `(a -> b -> b) -> b  -> [a]`?

In my opinion, the recursion pattern should be

```
fold f z (x:xs) = f x (fold f z xs)
```

However, shortly after in the lecture, you can find the following statement:

```
fold f z [a,b,c] = a `f` (b `f` (c `f` z))
```

This reinforces the so-called mistake, so I guess there must be a mistake in my head instead!

Shouldn't it be more like the following ?

```
fold f z [a,b,c] = `f` a (`f` b (`f` c z))
```

Am I missing a point, or is it a double mistake in the lecture?

Comment: *There seems to be an inversion between `z` and `f` [...]*. Yes, you're correct.

Comment: This is an exemplary school related question. Nice to see they do exist.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> There seems to be an inversion between `z` and `f` inside the recursion pattern: otherwise how could `z f xs` match `(a -> b -> b) -> b  -> [a]`?

You're correct, the types don't align, and GHC is quick to let you know if you try to define `fold` as given:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘a -> b -> b’ with actual type ‘b’
  ‘b’ is a rigid type variable bound by
      the type signature for fold :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
      at test.hs:1:9
...
```

> However, shortly after in the lecture, you can find the following statement:
>
> ```
> fold f z [a,b,c] = a `f` (b `f` (c `f` z))
> ```
>
> This reinforces the so-called mistake, so I guess there must be a
>   mistake in my head instead!
>
> Shouldn't it be more like the following ?
>
> ```
> fold f z [a,b,c] = `f` a (`f` b (`f` c z))
> ```

No. Once you've defined `fold` correctly, this unfolding of the definition is correct. The author is simply using the backtick notation to use function `f` as an infix operator:

```
fold f z [a,b,c] = a `f` (b `f` (c `f` z))
```

is equivalent to

```
fold f z [a,b,c] = f a (f b (f c z))
```

but is perhaps more readable if you think of `f` as binary function such as `(+)`; compare

```
fold (+) 0 [1,2,3] = 1 + (2 + (3 + 0))
```

to the less readable

```
fold (+) 0 [1,2,3] = (+) 1 ((+) 2 ((+) 3 0))
```

Comment: Ok ! Aha moment ! The backtick notation wasn't explained as clearly as you just did in the lecture yet (but maybe I missed an intro page...). Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

The code `fold f z (x:xs) = f x (fold z f xs)` should indeed be `fold f z (x:xs) = f x (fold f z xs)`.

The second part is correct though, since (pay attention to the backticks)

```
f x y == x `f` y
```

we have

```
a `f` (b `f` (c `f` z)) == f a (f b (f c z)))
```

Comment: Thanks ! This backtick notation wasn't actually clear in my head.